# Change the values of JSON file but keep the structure

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a JSON file like this:

```
{
    "public": {
        "hello": "world",
        "bye": "stranger"
    }
}
```

I then have a form where I can edit the values of `hello` and `bye`.

```
var keys = [];
var values = [];

$.each($(event.currentTarget).find('input'), function(key, val) {
    if($(this).attr('name') == 'skey') {
        keys.push($(this).val());
    }

    if($(this).attr('name') == 'svalue') {
        values.push($(this).val());
    }
});
```

And in the method I manipulate it

```
var rootDir = process.cwd().split('.meteor')[0];
rootDir = rootDir.replace(/\\/g, "/");
rootDir = rootDir + "private/";
var fileName = 'settings.default.json';
var filepath = rootDir + fileName;

for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        obj[i] = values[i];
    }
}

fs.writeFileSync(filepath, JSON.stringify(obj), 'binary');
```

The problem is that it would print
`["new value of hello", "new value of bye"]` and I, unfortunately, have no idea how to make it look like:

```
{
    "public": {
        "hello": "new value of hello",
        "bye": "new value of bye"
    }
}
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `obj` is the object you want to modify:

```
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    obj[keys[i]] = values[i];
}
```